# Emulator for Mobile Devices compatible with Visual Studios 2019 for Web Development

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I feel like I am missing something obvious. . .so any help is appreciated.

I am developing an ASP web site in Visual Studios 2019 on a windows 10 laptop (though not relevant, using C# and SQL).  I would like to launch my site into an emulator where I can fine tune the css/html for mobile phones/tablets etc.  I originally thought that would be easy to find. . .but anything I find seems to be antiquated and abandoned (ie Microsoft Emulator for VS2015), or specifically for mobile app development (ie Xamarin).

My goal is a single site that is accessible from laptops and mobile phones alike.  I have built separate Site.Masters for standard and mobile, but at the moment, the only way I can accomplish any dev is by a full deployment to my live site (which is not conducive to css/html tweaking).

Anybody know of a good local emulator I could use on my WIndows 10 laptop?  Ideally accessible from the browser selection in VS 2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome then try Ctrl+Shift+I then try Ctrl+Shift+M you can find your web page in different screen sizes.

[image]

Comment: That might work, looks good at a glance. . .I had glanced in the chrome dev tools before and didn't see where to select this. . .what does Ctrl+Shift+M open?

Comment: This is really helpful. . .the one problem I am having is that I cant seem to refresh the css that is being loaded to chrome.  It is the version that was loaded the first time I launched the site there in debug. . .no matter what changes I make, closing browser, restarting debugger, etc. . .the css it loads remains the ORIGINAL and does not include the edits that I have made.  I do love the feature in the dev tools where I can manually edit the css to see what works well though!

Comment: I just updated my answer with an image please check. If that is not helpful then try android emulator https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

Comment: Thanks, this definitely has me underway.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: This is helpful, but I don't believe it'll emulate the exact behavior (for example, clicks vs taps) you'd see on a mobile browser.